# Execute bash script from URL

Tags: linux, bash, curl

Say I have a file at the URL `http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt` that contains a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello, world!"
read -p "What is your name? " name
echo "Hello, ${name}!"
```

And I'd like to run this script without first saving it to a file. How do I do this?

Now, I've seen the syntax:

```
bash < <(curl -s http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt)
```

But this doesn't seem to work like it would if I saved to a file and then executed. For example readline doesn't work, and the output is just:

```
$ bash < <(curl -s http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt)
Hello, world!
```

Similarly, I've tried:

```
curl -s http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt | bash -s --
```

With the same results.

Originally I had a solution like:

```
timestamp=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
curl -s http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt -o /tmp/.myscript.${timestamp}.tmp
bash /tmp/.myscript.${timestamp}.tmp
rm -f /tmp/.myscript.${timestamp}.tmp
```

But this seems sloppy, and I'd like a more elegant solution.

I'm aware of the security issues regarding running a shell script from a URL, but let's ignore all of that for right now.

Comment: If you do end up creating a temporary file, you should probably be using `mktemp` instead of rolling your own solution

Comment: `cmd <<foo ` is heredoc syntax in most shells and probably not what you want.

Answer (score 296, accepted):

```
source <(curl -s http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt)
```

ought to do it. Alternately, leave off the initial redirection on yours, which is redirecting standard input; `bash` takes a filename to execute just fine without redirection, and `<(command)` syntax provides a path.

```
bash <(curl -s http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt)
```

It may be clearer if you look at the output of `echo <(cat /dev/null)`

Comment: Thanks, this made it clear what was going on.

Just curious, what is the advantage of using that initial redirection? I ask because for RVM installation, they use the command:

`bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)`

Why not just:

`bash <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)`

Comment: @Tristan: If they're running an interactive install script/program (commercial installer package, or an installer whuch also supports custom installation types), they can provide it default answers.

Comment: Small note: if wget is available but curl is not (e.g. on a stock Ubuntu desktop system), you can substitute `wget -q http://mywebsite.com/myscript.txt -O -` for `curl -s http://mywebsite.com/myscript.txt`).

Comment: Be aware that you can't pass command line arguments to your script. `bash will_not_work foobar <(curl -s http://example.com/myscript.sh)` If you own the script you can use environment variables instead like so: `MYFLAG1=will_work bash MYFLAG2=foobar <(curl -s http://example.com/myscript.sh)` and it also works with pipes like so: `curl -s http://example.com/myscript.sh | MYFLAG1=will_work MYFLAG2=foobar bash` This of course requires that you use MYFLAG1 and MYFLAG2 instead of $1 and $2

Comment: $ sudo bash <(curl -s http://xxx)          got error:    bash: /dev/fd/63: Bad file descriptor

Comment: @Jake Just a guess, but can it be that you are running `bash` as root, but 'curl' as a standard user? I'm not sure if Linux splits up file descriptors based on user, or at least restricts them to the user that created them.

Comment: @Jake Try running `su`, then while you are root, run the command without `sudo`.

Comment: If the script you're downloading needs to change environment variables like the path, this won't work. Is there a way to do this that allows changing the environment variables in the executing environment?

Comment: The first solution (the one using source) did not work at all. The second worked somewhat but has its limitations. It is executing the script from the URL in a subshell. I have some functions defined in the script that I would like to use in the parent. Is there anyway to achieve that? Or am I out of luck and the only solution is to copy that script in a temporary file and then source it?

Comment: How can you send arguments to a file executed this way?

Comment: The source version affects the current session, which means if your remote script calls `exit` (e.g. for an error) then it will drop you out of your session.  The bash version works better for this, and also allows environment variables to be set locally in the script without persisting.

Answer (score 116):

This is the way to execute remote script with passing to it some arguments (arg1 arg2):

```
curl -s http://server/path/script.sh | bash /dev/stdin arg1 arg2
```

Comment: this breaks stty :\ use `bash <(curl ... ) ` if you use stdin

Answer (score 78):

For bash, Bourne shell and fish:

```
curl -s http://server/path/script.sh | bash -s arg1 arg2
```

Flag "-s" makes shell read from stdin.

Comment: this should work in most shells, while the accepted answer does not work with *fish*, for example.

Comment: What is `arg1 arg2`?. Can I call just `curl -s http://server/path/script.sh | bash -s`?

Comment: @Nairum Yes, you can call without arg1 and arg2, which are parameters passed to script.sh. If script.sh requires parameters to be able to execute, you can add as many parameters as you like. Having 2 parameters is just an example.

Answer (score 21):

Use:

```
curl -s -L URL_TO_SCRIPT_HERE | bash
```

For example:

```
curl -s -L http://bitly/10hA8iC | bash
```

Answer (score 16):

Using `wget`, which is usually part of default system installation:

```
bash <(wget -qO- http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt)
```

Comment: RTFM: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html. |||  -q == --quiet == "Turn off Wget’s output."  |||   -O- == --output-document=- ==  If ‘-’ is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output.

Answer (score 13):

You can also do this:

```
wget -O - https://raw.github.com/luismartingil/commands/master/101_remote2local_wireshark.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 12):

You can use `curl` and send it to `bash` like this:

```
bash <(curl -s http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt)
```

Answer (score 12):

I often using the following is enough

```
curl -s http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt | sh
```

But in a old system( kernel2.4 ), it encounter problems, and do the following can solve it, I tried many others, only the following works

```
curl -s http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt -o a.sh && sh a.sh && rm -f a.sh
```

Examples

```
$ curl -s someurl | sh
Starting to insert crontab
sh: _name}.sh: command not found
sh: line 208: syntax error near unexpected token `then'
sh: line 208: ` -eq 0 ]]; then'
$
```

The problem may cause by network slow, or bash version too old that can't handle network slow gracefully

However, the following solves the problem

```
$ curl -s someurl -o a.sh && sh a.sh && rm -f a.sh
Starting to insert crontab
Insert crontab entry is ok.
Insert crontab is done.
okay
$
```

Answer (score 12):

The best way to do it is

```
curl http://domain/path/to/script.sh | bash -s arg1 arg2
```

which is a slight change of answer by @user77115

Answer (score 8):

Also:

```
curl -sL https://.... | sudo bash -
```

Comment: What dose the last strip mean?

Comment: From the bash man page: A  -- signals the end of options and disables further option processing.  Any arguments after the -- are treated as filenames and arguments.  An argument of - is equivalent to --.

Answer (score 4):

Just combining amra and user77115's answers:

```
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lingtalfi/TheScientist/master/_bb_autoload/bbstart.sh | bash -s -- -v -v
```

It executes the bbstart.sh distant script passing it the -v -v options.

Answer (score 2):

Is some unattended scripts I use the following command:

`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL <URL>)"`

I recommend to avoid executing scripts directly from URLs. You should be sure the URL is safe and check the content of the script before executing, you can use a SHA256 checksum to validate the file before executing.

Answer (score 2):

instead of executing the script directly, first download it and then execute

```sh
SOURCE='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cci-emciftci/123123/raw/123123/sample.sh'

curl $SOURCE -o ./my_sample.sh
chmod +x my_sample.sh
./my_sample.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

This way is good and conventional:

```
17:04:59@itqx|~
qx>source <(curl -Ls http://192.168.80.154/cent74/just4Test) Lord Jesus Loves YOU
Remote script test...
Param size: 4

---------
17:19:31@node7|/var/www/html/cent74
arch>cat just4Test
echo Remote script test...
echo Param size: $#
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the script run using the current shell, regardless of what it is, use:

`${SHELL:-sh} -c "$(wget -qO - http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt)"`

if you have `wget`, or:

`${SHELL:-sh} -c "$(curl -Ls http://mywebsite.example/myscript.txt)"`

if you have `curl`.

This command will still work if the script is interactive, i.e., it asks the user for input.

Note: OpenWRT has a `wget` clone but not `curl`, by default.

Answer (score -4):

```
bash | curl http://your.url.here/script.txt
```

actual example:

```
juan@juan-MS-7808:~$ bash | curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JPHACKER2k18/markwe/master/testapp.sh


Oh, wow im alive


juan@juan-MS-7808:~$
```

Comment: This is straight up wrong. Test your scripts before posting and don't fake output.