# How to use curl in a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, curl, sh

I'm trying to run this shell script in order to install RVM in an Ubuntu box

```
#!/bin/bash
RVMHTTP="https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer"
CURLARGS="-f -s -S -k"

bash < <(curl $CURLARGS $RVMHTTP)
```

but I get the following error

> Syntax error: Redirection unexpected

Also tested not using the variables, but same result, could you tell what I'm missing?

Comment: Your question has been already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735666/execute-bash-script-from-url

Comment: I tried it on my mac and it worked fine. I guess it's Ubuntu's bash (which I believe is dash). You might want to check the man page for dash.

Comment: `http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash`

Comment: If you get "redirection unexpected" it probably means you were using `sh` instead of `bash`, in spite of the shebang line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                     
CURL='/usr/bin/curl'
RVMHTTP="https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer"
CURLARGS="-f -s -S -k"

# you can store the result in a variable
raw="$($CURL $CURLARGS $RVMHTTP)"

# or you can redirect it into a file:
$CURL $CURLARGS $RVMHTTP > /tmp/rvm-installer
```

or:

[Execute bash script from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735666/execute-bash-script-from-url)

Answer (score 6):

```
url=”http://shahkrunalm.wordpress.com“
content=”$(curl -sLI “$url” | grep HTTP/1.1 | tail -1 | awk {‘print $2′})”
if [ ! -z $content ] && [ $content -eq 200 ]
then
echo “valid url”
else
echo “invalid url”
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, your example is looking quite correct and works well on my machine. You may go another way.

```
curl $CURLARGS $RVMHTTP > ./install.sh
```

All output now storing in `./install.sh` file, which you can edit and execute.