# Issues installing rvm on ubuntu 11.04 Server

Tags: installation, rvm, ubuntu-11.04

I am trying to set up RVM On Ubuntu 11.04 Server.

Making use of a multi user install..

The error I am currently getting is:-

```
$  sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
-sh: Syntax error: redirection unexpected
$
```

I am not sure whats wrong with the command, as I am using an exact copy of the command from the [RVM installation guide](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)

Any inputs, could be really helpful..

When I login as root, I am able to atleast run the command and install rvm. But the rvm gives me a command not found.

```
root@host:/home/dir_name# sudo bash -s stable < <(curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )
Downloading RVM from wayneeseguin branch stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  796k  100  796k    0     0   139k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--  261k

Upgrading the RVM installation in /root/.rvm/
installing - /root/.rvm/man/man1/rvm.1.gz -
installing - /root/.rvm/man/man1/rvm.1 -
    RVM system user group 'rvm' exists, proceeding with installation.

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

# RVM:  Shell scripts enabling management of multiple ruby environments.
# RTFM: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/
# HELP: http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=rvm (#rvm on irc.freenode.net)
# Screencast: http://screencasts.org/episodes/how-to-use-rvm

# In case of any issues read output of 'rvm requirements' and/or 'rvm notes'

Upgrade of RVM in /root/.rvm/ is complete.

# root,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   I sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne

root@host:/home/dir_name# rvm
No command 'rvm' found, but there are 19 similar ones
rvm: command not found
```

Few points to note, wrt what I tried:-

Initially, rvm was installed for me in the path:-

/usr/local/rvm

but somehow rvm command doesn't seem to recognize the path where it is insalled, if I am guessing correctly.

I also tried [install if root only](http://beginrescueend.com/support/faq/#root) , the installation path changes(to /root/.rvm/ ) but still I face the same issue.

I have a user, with loginname "user1" is there a way, I can let the user1 identify the rvm path, which has the post installation files, so that the command can be recognized

Thank you..

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318678/how-to-use-curl-in-a-shell-script

Comment: btw, multiuser installation of RVM is unrecommended.

Comment: @volodymyr: Can u pls share details as to why is multiuser installation not recommended.. Thanks..

Comment: In case of single user installation you don`t need root access at all, everything is executed with privileges of current user, so it`s easier to achieve better security. In case of multiuser installation you need root access, so it can cause security issues. Also multi-user installation(not mixed-mode) uses same gemsets and rubies for all users, so it can be little uncomfortable(while in single-user and mixed-mode install every user can have own versions of rubies and  gemsets )

Comment: @volodymyr: Thanks for your insights... A multi user install can also create different gemsets and use different ruby versions.. AFAIK.. I don't really get the reason of this not being there for a multi user..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fix did it:-

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: Also, it looks like I will have to enter this command every time i want to use RVM.. any permanent solution to this when I boot linux ..? or change my user to be "root" or "any" user ... Wondering.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Run this command :::

bash -s stable < <( curl -s https://raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer )

Comment: Thanks @swati but I already have an answer that worked for me. I'm sorry, I hadn't just marked it as 'accepted'