# Run python, with a parameter, on a cURL command on one line

Tags: python, bash, curl

I want to run the following commands in one line:

```
$ curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O
$ python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region eu-west-2
```

How can I do this?

I tried the following

```
$ curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -s | python --region eu-west-2
```

But I get the error:

```
Unknown option: --
```

Comment: you forgot `./awslogs-agent-setup.py` after `python`, but that's not all, it's looks like `./awslogs-agent-setup.py` expect to read a specific file on filesystem - so you will have to update it so it can read curl's output directly as argument

Comment: @Arount `awslogs-agent-setup.py` is the file being downloaded, he wants to execute it directly from the `curl` output rather than put it into a local file to execute it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could let the `python` interpreter read from `stdin` using `/dev/stdin` (similar to `python -`) and pass the additional arguments alongside.

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -s |\
     python /dev/stdin --region eu-west-2
```

As [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) points out using `/dev/stdin` could be OS specific in which case using `python -` would be more standard

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -s |\
     python - --region eu-west-2
```

As `curl` outputs the file content to stdout, you can pipe it over to the standard input of the interpreter.

Or use process-substitution feature in `bash` (`<()`), which lets you treat the output of a command as if it were a file to read from

```
python <(curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -s) --region eu-west-2
```

Comment: You can use `-` as the filename. Python follows the standard convention of treating `-` as a filename to mean standard input, then you're not depending on the OS-specific `/dev/stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `&&`

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O && python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region eu-west-2
```

and if you want to do without creating a file just to delete later, do this:

```
curl -s https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py | python /dev/stdin --region eu-west-2
```

[Execute bash script from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735666/execute-bash-script-from-url)

Comment: I don't want to create an uneeded file just to delete it

Comment: Your second solution seems the same as @Inian answer, except it is in more detail and has more options